# Error message in the header of my site - how to fix?

Tags: php, header

I have an error message appearing in the header section of my site and don't know what's the reason for that. It seems like a bug but I don't know the reason and how to fix that!

Comment: Good of you to obscure the error information, how should we know what the problem is?

Comment: @PeterR: The obscured part is just the actual path. The error is well-known from the message posted. Having it as an image is however completely useless.

Comment: Email me your page and any included/required files to mail@charliejsford.co.uk or upload them somewhere and I will take a look for you

Comment: Thank you, do you have Skype?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your site is trying to set something on the header (perhaps a cookie) after the response was sent. We need to see the code responsible. Most likely you need to move some of your code around in your file (perhaps the thing on line 8 should be before the thing on line 1?)

Comment: Yeah I see but it seems like a bug. I just added Google Analytics snippet to the header! Even when I remove that this message is there!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is present in the error message itself; headers cannot be set after output has been sent to the browser. When PHP first outputs any actual content to a browser, it has to send the HTTP headers first. After the headers has been sent, any new headers can't be added to the response, as the HTTP protocol now is in the actual body of the response. The error message shows you which line started the output (line 1), and which line tried to set the header (line 8).

To avoid the issue you can use `ob_start` and output buffering, although I'd strongly suggest separating displaying HTML from the code setting the headers, by either using a template language such as Smarty or twig, or a more extensive framework with a complete MVC model.

Comment: Yeah but I can't understand the problem here. I just added a Google Analytics code to the header and before that there were no such message.

Comment: If the Google Analytics code is at the top, it will be output before the header is set, and since the output now has started, the error message is generated since a header can't be set after the headers has been sent.

Comment: Above the header there is a php code. I removed the php code and then the error message dissappeared but if I add it again the error message also appears again! Please tell me, what to do? It drives me crazy! I don't know how to fix that!

Comment: Of course the error message will disappear when you remove the PHP code: the PHP code is the reason why the error message appears, since it attempts to set a header value, when the headers has already been sent (because of output to the browser). Either you'll have to set the header first (before any output), rewrite the code to use a proper template system, use output buffering or not set the header at all. It's hard to say anything more specific as long as you're not showing any code.